# Is there a shortcut to organize lines

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, cloud9-ide, c9.io

Within the [Cloud9](https://c9.io/) IDE, is there a shortcut to organize the lines of the Code, similar to the shortcut in Eclipse -  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is in this section of their documentation. I am not quite sure what you are referring to when you say "organize lines of code", but all of the shortcuts for c9 are in the link.

https://docs.c9.io/docs/keybindings#section-code-manipulation

If you are referring to beautifying your code then this is what you are looking for is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> this will beautify your text. Which is provided in the link.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is just select all and should work as is.

***********UPDATE**************

With the information just provided, you are using `C++` Here is a link to a plugin you can install to help with adding features for that language

https://github.com/invokr/c9.ide.language.cpp

there may be a better one out there, but there are some out there.

Comment: I know that the Ctrl+A is to Select all in its behave same. What i need is the Ctrl+I that work in Eclipse . I tried what you said about Shift + Ctrl + B and he pop the follow message : "This code could not be beautified

"c_cpp" is not supported yet

Comment: I think I am unclear then what you are trying to do, could you explain a little more you are wanting to happen?

Comment: its called Correct Indentation in Eclipse.. you can see more in the other answer here in this thread ,  I post 2 picture that Illustrates it.

Comment: have you tried the `beautify text` shortcut? Does that do what you are wanting?

Comment: I already said I tried  Shift + Ctrl + B and he pop the follow message : "This code could not be beautified "c_cpp" is not supported yet – Roey Mizrahi 6 hours ago

Comment: I added more information based on which language you are using, let me know if this helps.

Comment: what I need to download? i entered to the link you provide but I dont understand what i need to do there.

Comment: Here are the instructions in that repo link I sent you https://github.com/invokr/c9.ide.language.cpp#installation-on-a-local-c9v3-instance

Answer (score 0):

see the next function (there is no meaning to the code) : 
[Before the Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEIWO.jpg)

Now I do Ctrl+I and see the code now : 
[After The Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSKa8.jpg)

Comment: This screenshot is from the Eclipse. I want the same action to do in the cloud 9.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text you want to beautify and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (on PC/Linux). At time of writing, this only works for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: In time, there certainly will be. I don't know if the plugin you referenced below provides this functionality. The README doesn't seem to mention support for beautification or anything similar but maybe I missed something.